# Get all the files in others Onedrive in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to list all files in another user's OneDrive.

I am calling `GET /users/{user-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children` but my problem is that I do not know how to get the `{item-id}`.

I tried using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/drives` but it is not showing any item ids.

Subsequently, once I get the id, I will use the copy command `POST /users/{userId}/drive/items/{itemId}/copy` to copy items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not know the ID or Path for the `DriveItem`, you'll need to start at the root of the `Drive` and walk the folder structure until your find the file(s) you're looking for.

Your first call would be to `/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/drive/root/children?$select=id,name,folder,file`. This will [list the children's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) `id`, `name`, and either the `folder` or `file` data (depending on the item type) from the `root` folder:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('id')/drive/root/children(id,name,folder,file)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"{etag},1\"",
            "id": "folderId",
            "name": "My Folder",
            "folder": {
                "childCount": 10
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"{etag},1\"",
            "id": "fileId",
            "name": "filename.ext",
            "file": {
                "mimeType": "type",
                "hashes": {
                    "quickXorHash": "hash"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You then execute the same call against each of the folders to get their children, repeating the pattern until your find the file you're looking for:

```
/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/drive/items/{folderId}/children?$select=id,name,folder,file`
```

Alternatively, you could simply [search for the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using `/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/drive/root/search(q='{search-text}')`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to query root to get childIDs for files/folders

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id}/drive/root/children
```